# Spring Batch how to set filepath in ExecutionContext for next step

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch workflow where I read from a flat csv file and write it a csv file.

This is what my ItemWriter looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyCSVFileWriter implements ItemWriter<RequestModel> {

    private final FlatFileItemWriter<RequestModel> writer;

    private ExecutionContext jobContext;

    public MyCSVFileWriter() throws Exception {

        this.writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();

        DelimitedLineAggregator<RequestModel> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<RequestModel> extractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        extractor.setNames(new String[]{"id", "source", "date"});

        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(extractor);

        this.writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        this.writer.setShouldDeleteIfExists(true);

        this.writer.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends RequestModel> items) throws Exception {
        this.writer.open(jobContext);
        this.writer.write(items);
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStepHandler(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        JobExecution jobExecution = stepExecution.getJobExecution();
        jobContext = jobExecution.getExecutionContext();

        this.writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(getRequestOutputPathResource(jobContext)));
    }

    private String getRequestOutputPathResource(ExecutionContext jobContext) {
        //***
        return resourcePath;
    }

}
```

I use the executionContext to extract some data used to calculate my `resourcePath` for my writer.

My next step after writing is uploading the file I have written to in previous step to a remote server. For this I need to store the file path which were calculated and store it ExecutionContext and make it available in the next step.

What is the best way to do this? Should I be doing this in a `@AfterStep` handler?

Comment: processing is chunk oriented so I think `afterWrite()` gets called each time. I prefer to set the detail in execution context and have a next step extract the file location and upload.

Comment: You are calling `this.writer.open` in the `write` method, this is incorrect. You need to make your MyCSVFileWriter implement `ItemStream` and call `this.writer.open` in the `ItemStream.open`.

Comment: thanks, amended as per your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be doing this in a @AfterStep handler?

Yes, this is a good option. You can store the path of the file that has been written in the job execution context and read it from there in the next step that uploads the file.